# Why this RewriteRule doesn't work?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a web site containing 3 pages (Home, page2, page3) ... in the second page there is a navigation bar, with 4 items (subpage1, subpage2, ...), that I use to replace the content of the page 2 with url variables! In other words, the second item of the navigation bar in page2 points to:

```
http://localhost/uk/page2/index.php?pg=subpage2
```

the item 3 point to:

```
http://localhost/uk/page2/index.php?pg=subpage3
```

Now I would like to use more friendly urls via `.htaccess`!

I've written this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /uk/page2/(.*)/$ /uk/page2/index.php?pg=$1
```

in the `.htaccess` placed in the root!

But doesn't work!
Please help!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you're using .htaccess you don't have the leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uk/page2/(.*)/$ /uk/page2/index.php?pg=$1
```

Comment: Try just putting some rubbish in the .htaccess - you should get 500 Server Error. If you don't, your .htaccess isn't being loaded

Comment: @coder: mod_rewrite can only rewrite the URL you are requesting. So you need to request `/uk/page2/subpage2/` to see if the rewrite works.

Comment: OK! Thanks ... I'm sorry but I'm beginner in apache and php!

Answer (score 3):

G'day,

I'd suggest enabling the RewriteLog config option at a high level to check what's actually happening under the covers.

```
Has AllowOverides been enabled?</obvious> (-:
```

Seems like you're out of luck using .htaccess

> Unbelievably mod_rewrite provides URL manipulations in per-directory context, i.e., within .htaccess files, although these are reached a very long time after the URLs have been translated to filenames. It has to be this way because .htaccess files live in the filesystem, so processing has already reached this stage. In other words: **According to the API phases at this time it is too late for any URL manipulations**. - Apache mod_rewrite doc.s (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

It may be the trailing slash at the end, so change this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /uk/page2/(.*)/$ /uk/page2/index.php?pg=$1
```

to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)uk/page2(/?)(.*)$ /uk/page2/index.php?pg=$3
```

Another thing you should check is that you have AllowOverride set to All in your httpd.conf file, instead of None.  If it is set to None, you won't be allowed to do anything with .htaccess.